# PowerShell Code to Get the blob content to local

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage

PowerShell Code to Get the blob content to local.

Explanation of scenario  below-

I have code written me on how to download the blob folder level to the local & its working.
But my main focus is as below suggest me how this can be achieved.
storage account has container --folder1,2etc..
folder1 inside that will have dir1, 2 etc..,
now i want to get the content of the particular dir1 from folder 1 using PS.

The already working code on folder level is below for reference - guide me on the next level.

```
Connect-AzAccount -Subscription "XXXX"

$container_name = 'A/B/C' 
$destination_path = "C:\Users\Anirudh\Documents\upload\"  
$storage_account = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountKey "XXXXX" -StorageAccountName "XXXXX"
$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $container_name -Context $storage_account  
foreach($blob in $blobs) {  
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $destination_path  
    Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $container_name -Blob $blob.Name -Destination $destination_path -Context $storage_account  
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to download the blobs from a particular subfolder in a blob container, then you will need to specify the path to that subfolder in `-Prefix` parameter to [`Get-AzStorageBlob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-AzStorageblob?view=azps-3.6.1#parameters) Cmdlet.

Here's the sample code I wrote which download blobs from `A/B/C` folder in `test` blob container in development storage account.

```
$container_name = "test" 
$destination_path = "D:\temp\"  
$storage_account = New-AzStorageContext -ConnectionString "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
$path = "A/B/C" # This is the path of the sub folder inside the blob container.
$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $container_name -Prefix $path -Context $storage_account  
foreach($blob in $blobs) {  
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $destination_path  
    Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $container_name -Blob $blob.Name -Destination $destination_path -Context $storage_account  
}
```

Comment: Yeah really Thanks I just saw your code I am really happy Let me try fully and get back to you in case if I have  doubts...

Comment: @ Gaurav Mantri - Really great thanks on that always 100% working code tested. Can just share the idea, on how the path can be parameterised.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by `path can be parameterised`?

Comment: Ok I can just brief out the scenario in short here so that you can share if any code in PS. The $path which is now looking for specific subfolder level and not azure blob content,great but the same till some extent $path = A/B/C  till C it will be constant but after C subfolder it will look for dynamic download of contents/parameterization after C, it will have folder with 'daily dates' inside which it can have only 1 more subfolder. Now this - till C it should remain constant and then the PS code should be able to dwnload any date subfolder values, thereafter... Hope you got it ..

Comment: Old things are still got resolved by myself. Can anyone suggest, how to getdate and subtract it to previous date in PS code assign the current date to a variable.My current code is not allowing me to do that. $path = "A/B/C"
(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-mm-dd")
Get-Date -Format "dddd MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm K"
$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $container_name -Prefix $path$date -Context $storage_account  Quick help is great help for me.

Comment: Thanks to all here, the last comment which I stated also got completed for which ideas where recommended.  Can anyone suggest on the above that, i have multiple sub folders inside the blob path assume - A/B/C, Cis having folder1, folder2 etc.... How do I get all in one single folder using PS code. Adding Current working code in next comments.

Comment: Current working code as below- $container_name = 'XXXXXX'
$destination_path = "XXXXXX"  
$storage_account = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountKey "XXXXXXXX" -StorageAccountName "XXXXXX"
$path = "A/B" $date = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $container_name -Prefix $path$date -Context $storage_account   foreach($blob in $blobs) {  
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $destination_path  
    Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $container_name -Blob $blob.Name -Destination $destination_path -Context $storage_account  
}